# Doctrine - update many to many associations inside of event listener

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I`m a little bit confused with how to update related collection using doctrine events.

One entity is related with another through ManyToMany. For better understanding u can see examples below (User with Jobs). **The goal is: when User`s status is going to be changed then his jobs should also be changed from event listener**.

I have already tried `preUpdate` event:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getObject();
    foreach ($entity->getJobs() as $job) {
        $entity->getJobs()->removeElement($job);
    }
}
```

And also `onFlush` event:

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        foreach ($entity->getJobs() as $job) {
            $entity->getJobs()->removeElement($job);
        }

        $em->persist($entity);
        $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet(
            $em->getClassMetadata(Job::class),
            $entity
        );
    }
}
```

But in case when only status was changed outside the listener - user still have the same jobs(jobs were not changed from listener):

```
$user->setStatus('some-other-status');
```

But in case when collection was changed outside the listener - it works(jobs were changed from listener):

```
$collection = ... // some new collection of jobs
$user->setJobs(collection);
```

Any help is welcome.

---

Here are code snippets of entities:

User.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Job")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="_user_x_job",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="job", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
     * )
     */
    protected $jobs;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->jobs = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ...
}
```

Job.php:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Why won't you handle this inside the model? Don't use listeners, they are intented for low level, model unrelated actions like logging for instance. Stop using [anemic domain models](https://www.google.com/search?q=anemic+domain+model).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to avoid Doctrine Event Listeners at all for this task. Instead the whole behavior should be modeled directly in the User Entity: The setState() method can also hold the behavior to remove the job(s).

Then look out for `removeOrphans=true` doctrine mapping option:

Basically it works by removing the `Job` from the collection AND set its `User` to null. Doctrine will detect your orphaned jobs from the unit of work and automatically deletes them from the database when calling `persist($user); flush();`